# How did this memory corruption occur in c++?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, stdvector

I'm not sure I understand what the bug below is

```
const char* packs[] = {"zero","one","two","three","four",..."twelve"} //abbreviated for post

struct packinfo {
    char* data;
    int   len;
};

std::vector<packinfo> k;
k.reserve(10000);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    const char* data = packs[i];
    packinfo tobuf;
    tobuf.data = new char[strlen(data)];
    tobuf.len = strlen(data);
    memcpy(tobuf.data, data, strlen(data));
    k.push_back(tobuf);
}

for (int i = 0; i < k.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << "k[" << i << "]: " << k[i].data << ", ";
std::cout << std::endl;

for (int i = 0; i < k.size(); ++i) {
    packinfo& pack = k[i];
    bool foo = (i < 5);
    if (foo) std::cout << "inspecting k[" << i << "]: " << k[i].data << std::endl;
    delete pack.data;
    if (!foo) {
        k.erase(k.begin(), k.begin() + i);
        packinfo tobuf;
        const char* data = packs[10];
        tobuf.data = new char[strlen(data)];
        tobuf.len = strlen(data);
        memcpy(tobuf.data, data, strlen(data));
        break; //intentionally forgot to push_back
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < k.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << "k[" << i << "]: " << k[i].data << ", ";
std::cout << std::endl
```

;

The output of running the above is the following:

```
k[0]: zero, k[1]: one, ... , k[9]: nine, //all as expected
inspecting k[0]: zero
inspecting k[1]: one
...
inspecting k[4]: four
k[0]: ten^], k[1]: six, k[2] seven, k[3]: eight, k[4]L nine, //gargabe crept in
```

How did garbage creep into the beginning of the vector?

Comment: Reading [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be good for a debug question.

Comment: Ever hear of `std::string`?  Get rid of the char* stuff right away, and all of your problems will more than likely be solved.

Comment: Is it a learning-exercise to create your own string-type? Than always keep in mind whether you have a 0-terminated or a counted string (may be both at once), and do not forget the terminator respectively do not use cstring-functions.

Comment: The whole string part is irrelevant, I'm actually just trying to figure out a larger problem where std::string or strlen are not present but im trying to boil down the logic to something which still does allocations and memcopies to see if i can figure out the issue..strlen fixed to (strlen + 1) still places ten at the head of the vector which im not understanding how that happens

Comment: Since you allocate memory for `packinfo.data` using `new[]` you must free the memory using `delete[]` (note the square brackets). Hey did you know that `std::string` saves you from all this error-prone manual resource management?

Comment: oh, typo sorry, even after adding the bracket (proper delete) i get a ten in my final print out. I know i don't need char* and strlen with std::string but I'm trying to figure out how the ten gets into this example

Answer (score 3):

`strlen` gives you the length of characters in a nul-terminated string *wihtout counting the nul-termination character*. So you are dynamically allocating a data buffer that is too short to hold the target string:

```
tobuf.data = new char[strlen(data)]; // too short by 1
```

When you fill it using memcpy, there is no space for a null-termination for the string, and you wouldn't copy it if there was anyway, because the array is too short:

```
memcpy(tobuf.data, data, strlen(data)); // tobuf.data is not nul-terminated
```

When you attempt to read it as if it were a nul terminated string, you go out of bounds.

The immediate fix would be to use `strlen(data) +1`, but what you really should do is avoid the whole problem by replacing `packinfo` by `std::string`.

```
std::vector<std::string> k;
k.reserve(10000);
```

Comment: well strlen(data)+1 gets rid of the garbage..but why is ten the head of the vector when i dump the elements at the end?

Comment: @PalaceChan No idea. You have some other bug somewhere else.

Comment: +1 for "avoid the whole problem by replacing packinfo by std::string".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is these lines:

```
tobuf.data = new char[strlen(data)];
tobuf.len = strlen(data);
memcpy(tobuf.data, data, strlen(data));
```

Where do you add space for the string terminator?

C++ have the [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class, you should really use it as it will help you with these kind of problems.